# Debugging icons in Chrome Developer tools are not visible using vertical or auto layout settings

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am using:

- Chrome Version 58.0.3029.96 (64-bit) and
- Chrome Canary Version 60.0.3087.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit)

Currently I am not able to see "debugging icons" when developer tools is opened. I mean the icons are hidden, but when hovering the mouse on it, tool-tips appear and are selectable.
I also notice some similar issue with other icons in developer tools, for example "dock side" icons.

I notice this issue only on Windows 8.1, as on Windows 7 and 10 it works fine.

I have tried so far:

- Uninstall Canary and Chrome, reinstall Chrome only after computer restart.
- Reset browser.
- Disable all extensions.
- Using a Light or Dark theme.

I notice the icons show correctly only if in Developer/Settings/Panel layout is set to horizontal (with auto or vertical icons are not showing properly).

I would like to know:

- Can you reproduce this issue on Win 8.1?
- Are you aware of any related bug in Chrome?
- Do you know any workaround?

Notes:
In previous version of Chrome "debugging icons" were working just fine.

[image]

Comment: Try disabling GPU acceleration in Chrome. Or maybe you've updated the driver? Try reverting it.

Comment: @wOxxOm disabling GPU acceleration in Chrome fix temporary this issue. Thanks

Comment: Strange bug. Please file a bug at https://crbug.com. You can just link to this Stack Overflow post for the description of the bug.

Answer (score 0):

In order to temporary fix this issue on my machine I had to:

- Reinstall NVIDIA drivers from Device Manager in Windows.

After re installation I am able to use the browser with GPU acceleration.

Notes:
- Using NVIDIA drivers update from NVIDIA Control Panel did not fix my issue, I had to use driver update directly Device Manager.

I open a new bug for Chrome Team:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=718325

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue on Edge and by resetting the Developer tools settings from F12 > F1 > Restore Defaults and refresh, brought back the icon colors.